# How to capture on fail and on error event in MiniTest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I need to perform some action in MiniTest when ever an assertion fails or there is an error in a test. How to do this. Preferably something that can be written once globally in test_helper.rb

I tried minitest-retry like this

```
require 'minitest/retry'
Minitest::Retry.use!(
retry_count:  1,   
verbose: true,           
io: $stdout,             
)

Minitest::Retry.on_failure do |klass, test_name|
  puts "One test failed"
end
```

But giving the following error.

> `<top (required)>': undefined method`on_failure' for Minitest::Retry:Module (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/retry'

Minitest::Retry.use!(
  retry_count:  1,
  verbose: true,
  io: $stdout,
)

Minitest::Retry.on_failure do |klass, test_name|
  puts "One test failed"
end

class Minitest::RetryTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_fail
    assert false, 'test fail'
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like the issue with the installation. I reinstalled the gem and it worked.

Comment: Did it install same version ? Strange bug you had.